# Almost everywhere differentiable function with continuous derivative

Tags: real-analysis

Given a continuous function $f\colon(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ which is differentiable almost everywhere in $(0,1)$ with $f'(x)=g(x)$ for almost all $x\in(0,1)$. Now suppose that $g$ is itself continuous. Can you give me a simple rationale why $f$ must be differentiable everywhere in $(0,1)$?

Comment: For continuous functions this is false.  If you assume instead that  $f$ is absolutely continuous then you can prove that  $f'(x)=g(x)$ at every point.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson Can you give me a reference to the result for absolute continuous functions? I can't seem to find one in a hurry.

Comment: If  $f$ is abs. cont. and $f'=g$ a.e. then  $f(x)=f(a)+\int_a^x g(t)\,dt$ in the sense of the Lebesgue integral.  But $g$ is continuous so this is also a Riemann integral and any calculus student will promise you that $f'=g$ everywhere.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are learning real analysis it is wise to remember a few famous *counterexamples*.  I think that it is safe to say that the Cantor function is probably the most famous.

It gives you a surprising example of a nonconstant continuous function with a zero derivative almost everywhere.  It destroys your question and has destroyed many a bad conjecture in the past.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function

Comment: Thank you, that's a great counterexample!